# php why does it keep adding 2 minutes?

Tags: php, strtotime

When it's pulled from the db, it comes out like this:  2010-02-28 10:00:00

I'm formatting it (yes, I know that it's better to just do it in the query, but I don't have that option right now):

```
date('l F d, Y h:m A', strtotime($row['start']));
```

But, no matter what, it outputs like this: Sunday February 28, 2010 10:02 AM

Any idea why it's adding those two minutes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`m` in [date](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) means number of the month, not minute. What your looking for is `i`.
Like so:

```
date('l F d, Y h:i A', strtotime($row['start']));
```

You should really check the docs [here](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Oh, and, also, it's not better to format the date in the query, since your query needs not know the locale that you're using.

Comment: Next month he would come back saying the PHP is off by 3 minutes.  :)

Comment: But its better to do the conversion from internal timestamp format to `UNIX_TIME` in the query as it is locale independent. The internal timestamp format isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use i for minutes, m is for month, so the 02 is the month.